# How to add SSL certifcates from ssl.com to nodejs application

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, openssl

I have domain.name.crt file and domain.name.p7b file. Do I need any other file to add ssl to nodejs application? I checked other solution that require .pfx file, then how do I generate .pfx file?